# Let user specify timer time?

Tags: c#, windows, timer, textbox, dispatcher

I want the DispatcherTimer to read time values from the textbox : objTextBox.
I tried this code however it seems that TimeSpan is not compatible with strings or did I do anything wrong?

Error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'long'

Also; Does the Time have to look like this in textbox: 0, 0, 1 or 00:00:01?

Code here:

```
    private void testing()
    {
        string theText = objTextBox.Text;
        DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(listjob3_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(theText);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }
```

Comment: How are you presenting it to the user?  IE , Select a time in hours, minutes seconds?  It will depend on how you are gathering the value of the timer. Once that is determined we can than give you advice. The TimeSpan object constructor has TimeSpan (ticks), TimeSpan(hours, mins, sec),TimeSpan(days,hours, mins, sec) orTimeSpan(days,hours, mins, sec, milliSecs);  From what I see it is Ticks but I do not see any validating of the textbox value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert string to TimeSpan, use `TimeSpan.Parse(str)`

Comment: I get this error : System.TimeSpan.Parse(string, System.IFormatProvider)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'

What I wrote: 
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan.Parse(theText);

Comment: error is pretty self-explanatory, you should not place new infront of TimeSpan.Parse, because it is a static method, and not the type.

Comment: Can You Give me a example please?

Comment: dispatcherTimer.Interval =  TimeSpan.Parse(theText);

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your exception is here:

```
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(theText);
```

Use this instead:

```
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt64(theText));
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert to a `TimeSpan` from a `string` you could leverage [`TimeSpan.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx), but you'd have to conform to this format `[ws][-]{ d | [d.]hh:mm[:ss[.ff]] }[ws]` where:

```
ws    is Optional white space.
-     is An optional minus sign, which indicates a negative TimeSpan. 
d     is Days, ranging from 0 to 10675199.
.     is A culture-sensitive symbol that separates days from hours. The invariant format uses a period (".") character.
hh    is Hours, ranging from 0 to 23. 
:     is The culture-sensitive time separator symbol. The invariant format uses a colon (":") character.
mm    is Minutes, ranging from 0 to 59. 
ss    is Optional seconds, ranging from 0 to 59. 
.     is A culture-sensitive symbol that separates seconds from fractions of a second. The invariant format uses a period (".") character.
ff    is Optional fractional seconds, consisting of one to seven decimal digits.
```

so just converting days you could in fact use `TimeSpan.Parse` and just pass in the string - but if you wanted to convert minutes it would take some massaging of the input like this:

```
var input = string.Format("00:{0}", objTextBox.Text.PadLeft(2, '0'));
```

and so then you could issue `var timeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(input);` because you've formatted it properly and the `Parse` will succeed. Another option is to turn minutes into days I guess, but that would require some floating point work and is really, IMO, not as good of an option.

Answer (score 0):

@Sneakybastardd: have you **read** the [`TimeSpan` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) regarding constructor overloads? You'll note that none of them take string arguments: integer types are required.

After reading [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx), you might find these `TimeSpan` methods useful:

- `Parse()`
- `ParseExact()`
- `TryParse()`

With respect to format, See ["Standard TimeSpan Format Strings"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx) and ["Custom TimeSpan Format Strings"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx). Also do a little research on the various default TimeSpan formats for different cultures if that comes into play at all.